# Symbols that suggest directionality

Tags: symbols

I'm not quite sure if this is the right place for the question, so if not I'll happily take it down.  This could fall under linguistics or semiotics.  But in many hard sciences, we basically overload the arrow symbol for every single concept that suggests "directionality".  We use -> or some version thereof for functions, for inequalities, for connectivity, for "this implies that".  If you pick an asymmetric relationship in math, physics, econ, or you name it, there is a high probability that we represent it with some version of an arrow symbol.  I just enumerated four examples, but I would ballpark that around 50 concepts are expressed with some version of an arrow--and often we use exactly the *same* arrow symbol for multiple concepts, occasionally causing some amount of confusion.  The main exceptions I can think of are the set-membership and the subset relationships.  Even the subset symbol is overloaded in its own way and if you squint, looks like an arrowhead.  (Maybe like a Clovis arrowhead ... now I'm getting distracted.)

So anyway, it would be nice to sometimes choose a different symbol, evoking perhaps a different metaphor, for some of our asymmetric concepts.  But when I try to think of a symbol that evokes the notion of "from here to there" or something like that, I really struggle to pick something that isn't like shooting a projectile and yet still visually makes intuitive sense.  You could employ the metaphor of a river, and a simple squiggle can visually suggest this.  For some concepts where you want to conjure the notion of an indirect path this could be great, but what about concepts where you don't want to suggest indirect, winding paths?  (Either because the path is rectilinear or just because straightness/curvy-ness is irrelevant.)  The metaphor of a tree is nice, going from the ground toward the sky.  But in the sciences we usually like the direction to go left-to-right in flow with the written text.  So the up-down direction is only sometimes the one we want.

So I guess what I want is any ideas for symbols that are:

1. Visually, intuitively suggestive of a left-to-right direction on the page
2. Easy to draw in in-line text with a small number of pen strokes
3. Does not rely on the projectile metaphor
4. Usually suggesting either "This thing *is* to the left of that" or "This thing *goes* (or travels) from here to there."

Comment: I feel this is too broad. It's really just "idea farming", which is not on topic. There's no way to post a *definitive* answer and any voting would be based solely upon *"Yeah sure I like that idea."* Making it more a popularity contest than question <> answer.

Comment: @Scott I kinda figured that would be how most graphic design questions are, no?  Glancing over some of the other ones here, I guess most of the questions are actually "How do you do this thing in this software?"  So perhaps I misunderstood the focus of the community.

Comment: More subjective questions about theory and "best practice" are allowed. But the idea farming really isn't. Essentially, sharing knowledge is encouraged whatever that knowledge revolves around. But asking for free design/creative work (which this is) is not.

Comment: You are right that we have a lot of (too many?) software specific questions. It's not because it's the only focus of GDSE, I just think it's easier to ask such a question without it getting closed for being too subjective. In my opinion it's a bit of a problem we have here and I would love to see more questions about the theory and practice of graphic design. It's just so tricky to ask about these matters in an objective way. I agree with @Scott though that the problem with this question is that it will lead to different suggestions where you will pick the one you like most.